# OpenID on shared hosting

Tags: php, openid

I'm trying to use OpenID on my site but I get this error:

> Protocol https not supported or
>   disabled in libcurl

Can anyone please tell what does it mean? My website is running on shared linux hosting.

I use this script: http://gitorious.org/lightopenid

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using libcurl or is it being used from inside lightopenid?  Do you use https on your site or is it just your openid provider that does?  All of this information would be useful for people trying to help you.

Comment: I don't use libcurl elsewhere on my site, nor https...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means exactly what is says!  Your Open ID implementation (lightopenid) wants to communicate securely with an Open ID server over HTTPS - HTTPS is an optional feature in PHP/Curl and your web host has not enabled this feature.  Your options are to ask your hosting provider to enable this feature or to find an alternative which doesn't use Curl.  For the latter option, you'll probably find that alternatives also don't have the HTTPS option enabled.

Finally, you may be able to tell lightopenid to *not* use HTTPS, thus sidestepping this problem, however this doesn't seem like a very robust solution to me, use this only on dev sites, never with real users' accounts.